# Creating tree-lists of objects

Tags: c#, list, object

I want to create a hierarchy tree using lists of objects

the tree is something like this
I am unable to create the dynamic lists

[image]

```
//code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Student
    {
        string studentname;
        class Department
        {
            string departmentname;
            class Subject
            {
                string subjectname;
            }
            List<Subject> sub = new List<Subject>();
        }
        List<Department> dep = new List<Department>();

        public void getdata()
        {
            List<Student> stu = new List<Student>();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. you don't want department to be an inner class of student (simlarly for department/subjects). 2. I don't get where the tree comes into it, surely its just a department with a list of subjects which has references to students?

Comment: You need to clarify the question,is this a Q about how to populate your class? Display it?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with:

```
class Student
{
    string studentname;

    public Student(string studentname) {
        this.studentname = studentname;
    }

    public List<Department> Departments = new List<Department>();
}

class Department
{
    string departmentname;

    public Department(string departmentname) {
        this.departmentname = departmentname;
    }

    public List<Subject> Subjects = new List<Subject>();
}

class Subject
{
    string subjectname;

    public Subject(string subjectname) {
        this.subjectname = subjectname;
    }
}
```

and use the above structure in this way:

```
Student s = new Student("Student 1");
Department d = new Department("Department A");
s.Departments.Add(d);
d.Subjects.Add(new Subject("Subject A"));
```

Comment: While this is correct, the entire data structure falls apart when two students are trying to take part in the same subject